# Null object is String type in localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am coming from Java dev and new to javascript, can someone explains what is going on.

I am using `localStorage` to store my token in my browser.

```js
localStorage.token = 'xxx'
```

When the users sign out, we remove the token, here is the code

```js
localStorage.token = null
```

If we want to check wether the user is authenticated or not, we check the token

```js
const isAuth = localStorage.token !== null
```

Here is the thing becomes weird to me. After I marked `localStorage.token` to `null`,

the result of `localStorage.token !== null` is still true !

I had done some investigation,

I logged the `localStorage` object and found out the `token` variable is `"null"` instead of `null`.

Here is my assumption.

When the browser needs to store the localStorage, it iterates inside the object fields, after finding the `null` object, it use `toString` to store the final form?

Comment: There are built in JS function to achieve what you want. First you can use removeItem() to delete it from localstorage. If you use the function getItem(), it will give you an null on return!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localstorage in the browsers work only on the string types

```
localStorage.getItem('someItem');
localStorage.setItem('someItem', 'string value');
localStorage.removeItem('someItem');
```

Answer (score 1):

give a value or overwrite the one present in the localstorage with the function set item, like code below :

```
localStorage.setItem('token' , 'your token here ');
```

and for access the value  :

```
localStorage.getItem('token')
window.console.log("token :",localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use localStorage methods for setting, getting and removing token.

Check this link for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

And for checking weather the token exists or not you can do this:

```
const isAuth = !!localStorage.token
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use removeItem() to remove items from your localstorage.

```
localStorage.removeItem('token')
```

You can also use the function getItem() to retrieve the item.

```
localStorage.getItem('token')
```

This will return null when it doesn't exist.

> Documentation
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem
>
> https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Local storage can only save strings. That is a simple fact of life.
This is why `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` are synonymous with reading and writing from and to local storage.
null is no exception.